# Nginx serving dynamic php page

Tags: php, nginx, dynamic, xhtml

I'm trying to switch all the company servers to nginx. Till now all is going good, excepting for a webportal we use like an e-commerce.

The first problem is that the portal is made by an external company (a communication company...) so I'm not really documented on the architecture.

The web portal's main page is a php page that builds dynamically all other pages: there's a long switch-case, in every case there's an include pageN.php

example...

```
case "logout":
include ("shop/logout.php");
exit;
```

The problem come now, when I click on logout (or all other button), the passed URL is an xhtml (from www.site.com/index.php to www.site.com/aris.xhtml), and nginx return 404. The aris.xhtml not exist in the filesystem, i think it's autogenerated.

I've test different configuration, but the best result i can have is the same index page, also clicking on the button (no page is served but no 404).

Someone can explain me this type of web architecture, or point me out to a documentation?

Thanks in advance

The .htaccess file have the follow content:

```
#####################################################
# Script: htaccess Security                 #
# Version: 1.0                                      # 
#####################################################

# No web server version and indexes
ServerSignature Off
Options -Indexes

# Enable rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# Exclude ipn
#RewriteRule ^(ipn)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^ipn/.*$ - [PT]

# Block suspicious request methods
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD|TRACE|DELETE|TRACK|DEBUG) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

# Block WP timthumb hack
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (timthumb\.php|phpthumb\.php|thumb\.php|thumbs\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=1]

# Block suspicious user agents and requests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (libwww-perl|wget|python|nikto|curl|scan|java|winhttp|clshttp|loader) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (;|<|>|'|"|\)|\(|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%28|%3C|%3E|%00).*(libwww-perl|wget|python|nikto|curl|scan|java|winhttp|HTTrack|clshttp|archiver|loader|email|harvest|extract|grab|miner) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?\ HTTP/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/\*\ HTTP/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} etc/passwd [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} cgi-bin [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (%0A|%0D) [NC,OR]
# Block MySQL injections, RFI, base64, etc.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http:// [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=(\.\.//?)+ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=/([a-z0-9_.]//?)+ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=PHP[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12} [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\.\./|\.\.) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\: [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\: [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\: [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=\|w\| [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)/self/(.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)cPath=http://(.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*iframe.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^i]*i)+frame.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_(en|de)code[^(]*\([^)]*\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\[|\]|\(|\)|<|>).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (NULL|OUTFILE|LOAD_FILE) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\./|\../|\.../)+(motd|etc|bin) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1) [NC,OR]
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} concat[^\(]*\( [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union([^s]*s)+elect [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union([^a]*a)+ll([^s]*s)+elect [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (;|<|>|'|"|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|drop|delete|update|cast|create|char|convert|alter|declare|order|script|set|md5|benchmark|encode) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (sp_executesql) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

# Deny browser access to config files
#Order allow,deny
#Deny from all
#Allow from 1.2.3.4




<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://octo.web.site.it/$1 [R,L]
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$


#  cod + cat + cat2 + id
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/([0-9]*)_(.*).xhtml$ index.php?cod=$1&cat=$2&cat2=$3&id=$4&%1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)_([0-9]*).xhtml$ index.php?cod=$1&cat=$2&cat2=$3&id=$5&%1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*).xhtml$ index.php?cod=$1&cat=$2&cat2=$3&id=$4&%1 [L,QSA]

#cod + cat + cat2
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/([0-9]*)_(.*)\/([0-9]*)_(.*).xhtml$ index.php?cod=$1&cat=$2&cat2=$4%1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)_([0-9]*)\/(.*)_([0-9]*).xhtml$ index.php?cod=$1&cat=$3&cat2=$5%1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*).xhtml$ index.php?cod=$1&cat=$2&cat2=$3&%1 [L,QSA]

# cod + id
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/([0-9]*)_(.*).xhtml$ index.php?cod=$1&id=$2&%1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)_([0-9]*).xhtml$ index.php?cod=$1&id=$3&%1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*).xhtml$ index.php?cod=$1&id=$2&%1 [L,QSA]


# solo cod
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*).xhtml$ index.php?cod=$1&%1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*).xhtml$ index.php?cod=$1&%1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: And you are switching from Apache HTTPD? If yes then does the application have a .htaccess file? That's where URL rewrites happen. Post that and maybe someone can help you translate those rules to something nginx understands.

Comment: Thanks Sergiu Paraschiv, you have opened my mind!